# Opposite of Bloom filter?

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filter

I'm trying to optimize a piece of software which is basically running millions of tests. These tests are generated in such a way that there can be some repetitions. Of course, I don't want to spend time running tests which I already ran if I can avoid it efficiently.

So, I'm thinking about using a Bloom filter to store the tests which have been already ran. However, the Bloom filter errs on the unsafe side for me. It gives false positives. That is, it may report that I've ran a test which I haven't. Although this could be acceptable in the scenario I'm working on, I was wondering if there's an equivalent to a Bloom filter, but erring on the opposite side, that is, only giving false negatives.

I've skimmed through the literature without any luck.

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives

Comment: For completeness, this may be of interest: https://github.com/jmhodges/opposite_of_a_bloom_filter

Comment: There is one such thing with the funny name "Opposite of a Bloom Filter". Code: https://github.com/jmhodges/opposite_of_a_bloom_filter
blog: http://www.somethingsimilar.com/2012/05/21/the-opposite-of-a-bloom-filter/

Comment: I hope they call the opposite a bloom –> moold filter!

Comment: If you invert the bits of items in-flight you can turn a bloom into a sink, as you are blooming the negative space.

Answer (score 35):

Yes, a lossy hash table or a LRUCache is a data structure with fast O(1) lookup that will only give false negatives -- if you ask if "Have I run test X", it will tell you either "Yes, you definitely have", or "I can't remember".

Forgive the extremely crude pseudocode:

```
setup_test_table():
    create test_table( some large number of entries )
    clear each entry( test_table, NEVER )
    return test_table

has_test_been_run_before( new_test_details, test_table ):
    index = hash( test_details , test_table.length )
    old_details = test_table[index].detail
    // unconditionally overwrite old details with new details, LRU fashion.
    // perhaps some other collision resolution technique might be better.
    test_table[index].details = new_test_details
    if ( old_details === test_details ) return YES
    else if ( old_details === NEVER ) return NEVER
    else return PERHAPS    

main()
    test_table = setup_test_table();
    loop
        test_details = generate_random_test()
        status = has_test_been_run_before( test_details, test_table )
        case status of
           YES: do nothing;
           NEVER: run test (test_details);
           PERHAPS: if( rand()&1 ) run test (test_details);
    next loop
end.
```

Comment: I would add that any answer that combines a memory model with an eviction strategy, such as MRU, LFU or ARC, is a valid answer to this question.

Comment: while any lossy set with discrete membership could be said to be of the family of data structures considered "opposite" of sets with probabilistic membership, the LRU heuristic is a completely separate concern and has no direct relevance to the question. admittedly, so does my own answer (it assumes associativity 1), if we were to generalise. it is sufficient to say that there is a transform `f(set, item) -> set'` defined such that given a `set` and an `item`, a new `set'` is produced which may include `item` as a member, subject to cardinality constraints. the choice of `f` is irrelevant

Answer (score 25):

The exact data structure that accomplishes this task is a [Direct-mapped cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Direct-mapped_cache), and is commonly used in CPUs.

```
function set_member(set, item)
    set[hash(item) % set.length] = item

function is_member(set, item)
    return set[hash(item) % set.length] == item
```

Comment: Also on the order of millions, you could use a simple bit array. :)

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible to store the tests that you did **not** run? This should inverse the filter's behavior.

Comment: You can't do that because it's impossible to take elements out of a Bloom filter.

Comment: or a Cuckoo filter https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf

https://bdupras.github.io/filter-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

How about an LRUCache?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're leaving out part of the solution; to avoid false positives entirely you will still have to track which have run, and essentially use the bloom filter as a shortcut to determine the a test definitely has not been run.

That said, since you know the number of tests in advance, you can size the filter in such a way as to provide an acceptable error rate using some well-known formulae; for a 1% probability of returning a false positive you need ~9.5 bits/entry, so for one million entries 1.2 megabytes is sufficient.  If you reduce the acceptable error rate to 0.1%,  this only increases to 1.8 MB.

The Wikipedia article [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) gives a great analysis, and an interesting overview of the maths involved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a bit set, as mentioned above. If you know the no. of tests you are going to run beforehand, you will always get correct results (present, not-present) from the data structure.
2. Do you know what keys you will be hashing? If so, you should run an experiment to see the distribution of the keys in the BloomFilter so you can fine tune it to reproduce false positives, or what have you.
3. You might want to checkout HyperLogLog as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not much help - I don't think its possible.  If test execution can't be ordered maybe use a packed format (8 tests per byte!) or a good sparse array library for storing the outcomes in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you expect does not exist. Because such data structure must be a many-to-one mapping, or say, a limited state set. There must be at least two different inputs mapping to the same internal state. So you can't tell whether both (or more) of them are in the set, only knowing at least one of such input exists.

EDIT This statement is true only when you are looking for a memory efficient data structure. If memory is unlimited, you can always get a data structure to give 100% accurate results, by storing every member item.

Comment: @MartinKällman You're correct if memory efficiency is not a requirement because all the solutions proposed above require store of the original items (set_member in your case). After memory limit is met, it would give both false negative and false positive results. Bloom Filter never gives false negative results even when the false positive rate is rather high due to too many inputs.

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement for any associative array

Answer (score -1):

No and if you think about it, it wouldn't be very useful. In your case you couldn't be sure that your test run would ever stop, because if there are always 'false negatives' there will always be tests that need to be run...

I would say you just have to use a hash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I think it's still useful as I can always stop after a fixed amount of time. In fact I can keep on generating tests forever. But such a data structure will help me to ensure that most tests are in fact new ones without running out of memory fast.