# Is there any probabilistic data structure that gives false negatives but not false positives?

Tags: data-structures, hash, probability, bloom-filter

I need a space efficient probabilistic data structure to store values that I have already computed. For me computation is cheap but space is not - so if this data structure returns a false negative, I am okay with redoing some work every once in a while but false positives are unacceptable. So what I am looking for is sort of the opposite of a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: See also: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635728/opposite-of-bloom-filter?rq=1), [Link2](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives).

Comment: Old question, I know, but now you got me curious. What external occurrence causes a previously computed value to disappear and/or become invalid (if active, can you get notified, and if passive, how do you know or later discover that fact)? For example, where, how, and most importantly, **when** is a ***true-positive*** value "lost" such that it now needs to be, as you say, "redone." I can think of solutions heading off in a few different directions but all seem to require more specific details about the use case. Also, how cheap is "cheap," otherwise here's a full solution: `λx ￫ false`

Comment: @GlennSlayden Not the original poster, so almost definitely for a different use case: I'm generating pieces of data on the GPU, on the order of 2^n 'chunks' per input. However, almost all of the generated chunks end up being copies of other generated chunks, and therefore redundant data. I only need one copy of every unique chunk: Ideally, I'd be able to filter generated data so that the output buffer wouldn't fill up as quickly, which would allow me to significantly decrease the frequency of GPU to CPU data transfers for offloading that data.

Comment: Indeed there is: here is an article that contains a description of one: https://medium.com/hyperblogblog/probabilistic-data-structure-use-cases-b414574b8961#Invertible%20Bloom%20Lookup%20Table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For false negative you can use lossy hash table or a LRUCache.
It is a data structure with fast O(1) look-up that will only give false negatives.
if you ask if "Have I run test X", it will tell you either "Yes, you definitely have", or "I can't remember".

Pseudocode:

```
setup_test_table():
    create test_table( some large number of entries )
    clear each entry( test_table, NEVER )
    return test_table

has_test_been_run_before( new_test_details, test_table ):
    index = hash( test_details , test_table.length )
    old_details = test_table[index].detail
    // unconditionally overwrite old details with new details, LRU fashion.
    // perhaps some other collision resolution technique might be better.
    test_table[index].details = new_test_details
    if ( old_details === test_details ) return YES
    else if ( old_details === NEVER ) return NEVER
    else return PERHAPS    

main()
    test_table = setup_test_table();
    loop
        test_details = generate_random_test()
        status = has_test_been_run_before( test_details, test_table )
        case status of
           YES: do nothing;
           NEVER: run test (test_details);
           PERHAPS: if( rand()&1 ) run test (test_details);
    next loop
end.
```

Similarly Bloom filter for false positive

Comment: Please read the question. Bloom filter is exactly what I am NOT looking for.

Comment: HI Wrick , I modified my answer please let me know if this serves your purpose