# Data structure with no false positives and fixed size?

Tags: database, data-structures, synchronization, false-positive

I'm trying to create a data structure to sync two or three large (and growing) string-list databases efficiently. I know the specs of the data structure I need to implement, but I have no idea what fits the bill. I'm told that:

1: you can still possibly exchange some identical pages but should definitely not miss to exchange any non-identical pages (so false negatives ok, false positives not ok)

2: solution should involve exchanging a fixed tiny amount of data and then synching non-identical result pages using that information

3: should sync in one communication step rather than comparing then syncing in two steps

First I thought of a bloom filter because of the small fixed size, but this would in some cases not send queries that should have been sent, so seems like the opposite of what I want. If I did a cache instead it could work for no false positives, but wouldn't be fixed size.

Is there anything out there that fits both 1 & 2 criteria??

Comment: Even a Bloom filter, although fixed size, can't hold an unlimited amount of data. Depending on the number of pages you're talking about, you could use something as simple as a hash table that just stores the keys of the items. Set the table's capacity to the maximum number of documents you expect. Not nearly as space efficient as a Bloom filter, but it has the benefit of 0 false positives and 0 false negatives.

Comment: I thought that as a bloom filters capacity increases its false positive rate also increases, but the size stays fixed. I feel like given the specs that false negatives are acceptable and it should be fixed small size there must be something/some combination of things out there that is a better fit.

Comment: Bloom filter's FP rate increases as the number of items inserted into the filter approaches its capacity. That's why I suggested a standard hash table.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13263220/56778

Comment: You might take a look at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives. Hope that helps.