# Bloom filter inverse? possible?

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

From an interview question:

"Determine whether a word is in a stored list. The list doesn't fit into memory. No disk access allowed, for lookups, memory access only. No false positives allowed, false negatives ok."

Bloom filters do the exact opposite: False positives allowed, no false negatives allowed.

My thoughts: We cannot use a hash function since we might have collisions that violate the "no false positives" requirement. Even if using a counting bloom filter, a collision would still cause a false positive. I.E. two strings result in the same hashes, so when the first one is "inserted", and we do a lookup for the second one, it will show its there, although its not.

I think the answer is a bit array since we can't have false positives. Does that sound right?

Comment: what about open chained hashing? I think we should be able to use that.

Comment: For the question exactly as posed, just storing part of the list in a sorted array meets the requirements too :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any probabilistic data structure that gives false negatives but not false positives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263220/is-there-any-probabilistic-data-structure-that-gives-false-negatives-but-not-fal)

Comment: To bounce over @twotwotwo's answer, not storing anything meet the requirement too, always answer no.

Comment: I consider `a bit array` as an answer funny: while I have an inkling what an array may be, I have _no_ idea how it would be indexed or what the value at that index meant. (For list not much larger than memory, I might second _open chained hashing_ (with a limit on probes). If there are ample common prefixes, a trie may fit even if the list does not.)

Comment: How about this: Instead of a hash, create a 1-to-1 function that maps every word on disk into a number, find that position in a bit array and mark it as 1. We can always go back and recompute the number(index) of a word

Comment: or using Rabin–Karp. Consider list of words on disk as a long sentence, and run Rabin–Karp on it using the rolling hash

Comment: Depending on the implementation details, and the common prefixes in the list, you may be able to represent the entire list in a trie, even if the entire list itself doesn't fit in memory.  The trie would give definitive results.

Comment: they could say that the entropy of the data is high, or that there are no equal prefixes, effectively forcing a trie to contain all the words.

Answer (score 3):

I think an LRU cache will do. Since when we ask if a word is in the list, we either want "definitely yes" or "probably not," or said otherwise, no false positives allowed, but false negatives ok; then its Ok to say "probably not in list" even its there (probably not) and if the word happens to be in the LRU cache, then it will always answer "definitively yes"