# Storage algorithm for comparison against multiple, arbitrary values

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, comparison

I am currently writing a message queue that will require me to keep a history of the messages the server has already seen. I have unique, fixed-size ID fields for each message, which makes it trivial. However, I am concerned about the long-term prospect of storing the ID of every message, and later, the latency in comparing between them. My current IDs are 160bit in length (yes, SHA1).

What I would ideally like to know is if there is a way to compress multiple IDs into one field in order to save memory, and if there is, what the false-pos and false-neg rates for the algorithm are as a function of the message compression. Ideally, I do not really care about the false-negative rate, but care a **lot** about the false-positive, which makes comparisons like `agrep` pretty meh.

Comment: Naive question here. Why not use running numbers?

Comment: @AdamSmith: I did think of that. Cannot be done due to multiple servers having multiple possible running numbers.

Comment: (Think "peer to peer node distribution", where nodes relay messages from other nodes, and the message needs to hit everyone at least once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not really contain enough information to give a definitive answer, but you might want to take a look at [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: Thomas: I'll edit. Meanwhile...the idea behind Bloom filters is good. However, I'm looking for exactly the opposite property: no false positives, as many false negatives as needed. I do not mind re-sending data - I do mind data falling off the grid, though.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld [This](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives) / [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635728/opposite-of-bloom-filter) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using MD5 which is a 128 digest of each message. Collisions are obviously irrelevant, because you can always double check any match byte for byte. The advantage of 128 bit is that it is somewhat shorter (16 bytes) than SHA1.

You can store the MD5s in a radix tree. This will make the data compact and easily searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Persistent Hash Map or Persistent Set. Most Hash Map/Set implementation handles collision by comparison of the actual object.

This makes for an amortized constant-time lookup if all your key hashes can be stored in memory.